# Unity: Animate Sprite Shape Sprite?

Tags: unity

Is it possible to animate a sprite shape?  I don't see the Sprite Shape Profile in the animator properties, so I was just wondering if there's another way to do that.

To clarify:
Our game is 2D animated by hand, and one level has conveyor belts that span the level.  We can animate it normally, but that will end up taking more video memory than if we were able to animate the conveyors as tiled sprite shapes.  It may not end up being worth the effort to save the memory, but I figured it was worth a shot.  Because the sprites span the level, they end up taking up lots of space in a sprite atlas.

Comment: Can you clarify what specific animated appearance you want to achieve? Even if it's not possible through the Animation and Sprite Shape Profile features specifically, there may be other ways to achieve that goal.

Comment: Definitely, I just added a little blurb to the main question.  Thanks for asking!

Comment: Ah, I think you'll get much better answers if you ask "How can we efficiently animate the conveyors in this level" and show an example screenshot of what your conveyors look like / how they're set up. It generally pays to ask about the problem to solve / the end goal to serve, rather than about the stepping stone you hope might get you closer to it.

Comment: That's a good idea, I'll do that!

Comment: For future reference, it's generally better to edit an existing unanswered question, rather than post a second question about the same issue. Editing a question also bumps it in the feed, so you don't miss out on anything by recycling the existing post.